# What can I use to replace MessageBox.Show in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, messagebox, replace

I am developing a MVC intranet.

I'm more used to developing for windows, but I've been assigned this project.

I always used MessageBox.Show to display messages about exceptions.

What can I use to do it in MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery dialog:

```
<div id="msgDialog" title="Warning">Please select an item.</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
  // set up message dialog
  $("#msgDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: {
      " OK ": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
    }
  });

});

// to invoke:
    $("#msgDialog").dialog('open');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do

- You can use jQuery dialog.Check this out  http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog. It is super simple to use
- You can use Response.write in order to write whatever you want on the page
- You can use javascript alert to show a message.

Comment: I do want to do it from code behind. Whenever I catch a exception, I open some sort of dialog to inform the user about the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking the question in the wrong way.  You are implementing a web application which is a completely different paradigm from Windows development.  If you have a server side error you can handle it and write it to the html output or you can log it or you can do whatever you want.  You can store the exception in a string and place it in a javascript alert if you want something similar to a message box.

```
<script>
    alert('@Model.Exception');
</script>
```

Comment: This is the code where I catch exceptions. That's what I want to change.                                                             public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            Test test = _db.Tests.Find(id);

            try
            {
                ViewBag.RegionLevelId = new SelectList(_db.RegionLevels, "Id", "Name", test.RegionLevelId);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.message);
            }

            return View(test);
        }

Comment: How about ViewBag.Exception = ex.message;  then in the js: 
var e = '@ViewBag.Exception'; if(e != ''){alert(e)};

Answer (score 0):

You need to get used to the fact that MVC is Web-centric. You need to give client all necessary scripting to execute in the browser.
In this setup, you may send exception view to the client. If you want to show message box you need to bake in some JavaScript-based code into your view. 
In other words, you need to build everything on the server with intent that this will show and execute on the client, including JavaScript.
Even in ASP.net this is how you get dynamic functionality - you render one client-side code under certain conditions and other client code when conditions are different.